# php.ini does not update date.timezone

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, php.ini

I have apache and php running on OSX.

I have a simple page printing `phpinfo()`.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

In my php.ini, no matter what I write for date.timezone, phpinfo says `Europe/Zurich` (both Local and Master).

I know I am modifying the correct file because if I change some other flag (`short_open_tag`) I see the changes immediately (after apache restart). But changing the timezone to say

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

Nothing changes...

I've also tried

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

I'm going crazy - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question.

After some research, I've realized my version of PHP was packaged by Liip. According to their website (http://php-osx.liip.ch/), they state:

> Why is Europe/Zurich the default timezone? Where to change that?
>
> Because we are based in Zurich (and Fribourg and Lausanne). Change the
>   file in /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini to adjust that.

I did just that, solves it!

Comment: Where i can find this file "99-liip-developer.ini" on windows?